# PostMessage: Messages not received

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

I'm looking for some feedback on an issue that I can workaround, but want to understand better. I have some multithreaded code where a worker thread uses the Win32 API PostMessage function to post a message to the main UI thread in order to update a TreeView. Some of the posted messages sometimes fail to ever appear via the UI thread's message pump, despite my logging showing that the PostMessage returned successfully.

I've already found numerous explanations of how this could happen if I'd done something funky in my message pump, due to the presence of a modal message pump in certain circumstances, but I'm not doing anything funky.

I think (but would like confirmed) that my problem is due to calling PostMessage too early in the UI thread's lifetime. My WinMain calls CreateWindowEx to create its main window, and the WM_CREATE handler for that window indirectly launches the background threads that will, fairly quickly, call PostMessage using the main windows's HWND, possibly even before the WM_CREATE handler finishes, very likely before WinMain's message pump is started.

Is it possible/likely that some messages in this situation would be lost, even though PostMessage returned success? In testing, I've determined that adding a small delay (Sleep(50)) in the worker thread before it calls PostMessage is enough to prevent any message loss. However, I'm not convinced that this is solving the underlying problem so would like to know if I need to keep digging.

EDIT:

There's only one message loop in all my code and it's not doing anything unusual beyond calling the usual TranslateAccelerator etc:

```
 // Enter the message loop
 while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
   if (!TranslateMDISysAccel(hwndClient, &msg) && !TranslateAccelerator (hwndFrame, hAccel, &msg)) {
     TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
     DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Downvoters - please leave a comment to help me improve the question.

Comment: Such questions cry for a [mcve].

Comment: @zett42 - Please read the question carefully. There is only one sentence that is actually a question: 'Is it possible/likely that some messages in this situation would be lost, even though PostMessage returned success?'. I wasn't asking for help in diagnosing my specific code, I was asking a general question about the timing of when a message queue becomes fully open for business. Remy helped with a concise answer to that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've already found numerous explanations of how this could happen if I'd done something funky in my message pump, due to the presence of a modal message pump in certain circumstances, but I'm not doing anything funky.

Modal loops don't throw away window messages, unless they are coded wrong and don't pass unknown messages to `TranslateMessage()`/`DispatchMessage()` like they should.

> I think (but would like confirmed) that my problem is due to calling PostMessage too early in the UI thread's lifetime.

If that were the case, `PostMessage()` would simply fail, but you have already ruled that out.  As soon as a thread calls any `user32.dll` function, the message queue is created and can begin receiving messages, even if the queue is not polled right away.

> Is it possible/likely that some messages in this situation would be lost, even though PostMessage returned success?

No. Something else is going on. Either your message loop is filtering messages incorrectly, or a malformed modal loop is discarding messages, or you are simply posting to the wrong `HWND`. Hard to say as you did not show any of your code.

> In testing, I've determined that adding a small delay (Sleep(50)) in the worker thread before it calls PostMessage is enough to prevent any message loss.

What is your main thread normally doing during those 50ms? Sounds like something in your UI code is receiving and discarding your posted messages during that time.

On the other hand, how do the threads know which `HWND` to post to? Is your `WM_CREATE` handler passing its `hwnd` parameter to the threads, or are the threads relying on the `HWND` returned by `CreateWindowEx()`? In the latter case, `PostMessage()` should fail if called before `CreateWindowEx()` exits. Unless your receiving `HWND` variable is initially uninitialized and contains a random non-null value that `PostMessage()` interprets as a valid `HWND` elsewhere on the system.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Remy. I didn't post any code because it's complex multithreaded stuff and it would be too much to show all of it. I mainly wanted the 'No. Something else is going on' response, so thanks for that, I'll keep looking. I'll update the question with some more details.

Comment: Remy, thanks again... you prompted me to check some assumptions and I found that some of the PostMessage calls were indeed using an HWND variable before it was properly initialised. It has a value of 0 before initialisation which is valid for PostMessage, hence why the call succeeded.